# La librería keyboard de Python

Tags: python, keyboard

Tengo Python 3.11.2. He instalado la librería `keyboard` con `pip install keyboard`. Me aseguro con `pip list` de que esté instalada. Cuando en un programa intento importarla con import keyboard, VSC me marca un error en la palabra `keyboard`, como si no existiera. Si trato de ejecutar el programa, me salta un error diciendo que no se reconoce el módulo keyboard. Es decir, no me la reconoce, a pesar de que sí está instalada. A que se debe esto?

Comment: Visual Studio Code generalmente ejecuta las aplicaciones en entornos virtuales locales de python: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments. Asegúrate de instalar la biblioteca en el entorno de la solución dónde quieres usarla.

Comment: Otra posible causa, puede ser que tengas dos o más versiones de Python instaladas. Lo cual puede hacer que, por ejemplo, al usar pip se instale y liste en las librerías de python 2.7 pero tu programa se ejecute en python 3.11